# Python file input string: how to handle escaped unicode characters?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, decode

In a text file (test.txt), my string looks like this:

```
Gro\u00DFbritannien
```

Reading it, python escapes the backslash:

```
>>> file = open('test.txt', 'r')
>>> input = file.readline()
>>> input
'Gro\\u00DFbritannien'
```

How can I have this interpreted as unicode? `decode()` and `unicode()` won't do the job.

The following code writes `Gro\u00DFbritannien` back to the file, but I want it to be `Großbritannien`

```
>>> input.decode('latin-1')
u'Gro\\u00DFbritannien'
>>> out = codecs.open('out.txt', 'w', 'utf-8')
>>> out.write(input)
```

Comment: If you want to serialize Python unicode objects to a file why not try using the `cPickle` module?

Comment: The data is from http://downloads.dbpedia.org/3.5.1/de/persondata_de.nt.bz2
Using Python 2.6

Answer (score 9):

You want to use the `unicode_escape` codec:

```
>>> x = 'Gro\\u00DFbritannien'
>>> y = unicode(x, 'unicode_escape')
>>> print y
Großbritannien
```

See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html?highlight=codecs#standard-encodings) for the vast number of standard encodings that come as part of the Python standard library.

Comment: Nice. This one had *escaped* me.

Answer (score 4):

Use the built-in 'unicode_escape' codec:

```
>>> file = open('test.txt', 'r')
>>> input = file.readline()
>>> input
'Gro\\u00DFbritannien\n'
>>> input.decode('unicode_escape')
u'Gro\xdfbritannien\n'
```

You may also use `codecs.open()`:

```
>>> import codecs
>>> file = codecs.open('test.txt', 'r', 'unicode_escape')
>>> input = file.readline()
>>> input
u'Gro\xdfbritannien\n'
```

The list of standard encodings is available in the Python documentation: http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings