# How to convert unicode string like u'\\u4f60\\u4f60' to u'\u4f60\u4f60' in Python?

Tags: python, unicode, replace

I capture the string from a html source file using regex:

```
f = open(rrfile, 'r')
p = re.compile(r'"name":"([^"]+)","head":"([^"]+)"')
match = re.findall(p, f.read())
```

And I've tried:

```
>>> u'\\u4f60\\u4f60'.replace('\\u', '\u')  
u'\\u4f60\\u4f60'  
>>> u'\\u4f60\\u4f60'.replace(u'\\u', '\u')  
u'\\u4f60\\u4f60'  
>>> u'\\u4f60\\u4f60'.replace('\\u', u'\u')  
File "<stdin>", line 1  
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: end of string in escape sequence
```

Could that be done by str.replace()? Or need something more complex?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python file input string: how to handle escaped unicode characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811174/python-file-input-string-how-to-handle-escaped-unicode-characters)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> u'\\u4f60\\u4f60'.decode('unicode_escape')
u'\u4f60\u4f60'
```